# Error while executing UCM code on lists in R

Tags: r, list

I tried executing the UCM model in R but face the issue with the large values present in covariance matrices. The input data does not have large values though

```
ucm_train <- lapply(train_data, function(x) ucm(Value~0,data = x , level=T, irregular=T,slope=T,season=T,season.length=12))
```

> Error in is.SSModel(do.call(updatefn, args = c(list(inits, model),
>   update_args)),  :    System matrices (excluding Z) contain NA or
>   infinite values, covariance matrices contain values larger than 1e+07

This is what I get after I traceback

```
6 stop(paste0("System matrices (excluding Z) contain NA or infinite ", 
    "values, covariance matrices contain values larger ", "than ", 
    tol)) 
5 is.SSModel(do.call(updatefn, args = c(list(inits, model), update_args)), 
    na.check = TRUE, return.logical = FALSE) 
4 fitSSM(inits = inits, model = modelH, method = "BFGS") 
3 ucm(Value ~ 0, data = x, level = T, irregular = T, slope = T, 
    season = T, season.length = 12) 
2 FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
1 lapply(train_data, function(x) ucm(Value ~ 0, data = x, level = T, 
    irregular = T, slope = T, season = T, season.length = 12))
```

**EDIT**

The data looks like this

train_data is a list containing 16 dataframes and each dataframe has two columns

```
> head(train_data[[1]])  #checking the train dataset
      DateTime Value
811 2015-07-31  51.9
812 2015-08-31  51.0
813 2015-09-30  50.0
814 2015-10-31  49.4
815 2015-11-30  48.4
816 2015-12-31  48.0
```

Thank You.

Comment: Please provide the data to make it reproducible http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Hack-R  I understand that the input values which need forecasting impact this error but I am unable to understand anything beyond that.